# Datapicker allow invalid dates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, datapicker

I need allow date like '99/99/9999' when user doesn't know exact date, how can I implement this?

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    language: "pt-BR",
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true
})
```

Using this code, '99/99/9999' is converted to '07/06/9999'.

Here an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bvbtz2re/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/252/)**.

You could set the option **[`constrainInput`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput)** to false :

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    language: "pt-BR",
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true,
    constrainInput: false 
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i try this but i'm use bootstrap-datapicker and here this dont work

Comment: The tag in the first says `jquery-ui`!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`forceParse`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#forceparse) option setting its value to `false`. As the [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#forceparse) says:

> Whether or not to force parsing of the input value when the picker is closed. That is, when an invalid date is left in the input field by the user, the picker will forcibly parse that value, and set the input’s value to the new, valid date, conforming to the given *format*.

Here a live example:

```js
$('input.datum').datepicker({
  format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
  language: 'de',
  weekStart: 1,
  autoclose: true,
  assumeNearbyYear: true,
  forceParse: false
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <label>Date:</label>
    <input class="datum" type="text" name="vondatum" required>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```