# Bootstrap Datetimepicker overrides dates

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Bootstrap Datetimepicker in my website.
The picker calendar works perfectly but when I write a date which is bady formatted, it will clear it and fill the text input with the last correct date (or just erase the field if none was entered before).

Worse than that, it will sometimes arrange dates to fit the format I've mentioned. For example, entering "102" and clicking out of the input zone will fill "10/02/2018".

I would like to force that behavior, and to keep user input in the text area, even if wrong format (I'll check it afterwards)

What am I missing here ?

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Date de naissance<label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group date date-default input-date datetimepicker col-lg-7" style="float: none;">
                            <input id="datenaissance" name="datenaissance" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="JJ/MM/AAAA" value=""/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <img src="../images/icon/calendrier.png" alt="calendrier">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried turning the datetimepicker validation off and see of that works? Or turn constrains off? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014423/datapicker-allow-invalid-dates

Comment: Actually it does not recognize datepicker function, I don't know why...

Comment: I tried with datetimepicker instead of datepicker with that option, no change.